# PHP - can Require_Once be used as an Object?

Tags: php

I am trying integrate a way of a user being able to store there configuration settings into a blank PHP file like this:

```
<?php // Configuration.php
    $con = array(
        'host' => 'host'
        'user' => 'username',
        'pass' => 'password',
        'name' => 'dbname'
    );
?>
```

What I have tried:

```
class Configuration{

    public $database = require_once 'Configuration.php';

}

$config = new Configuration;
print_r($config->database->con);
```

Is this possible or not? There will be a display on the Configuration.php page when accessed so I don't want to `include` the page in the site, only `require` its *properties*.

Thanks in advance.

> **[Updated working code for viewers](https://codeshare.io/75qL1) - Use of Class and Constructors by @Yoshi**

**Config.php** -

```
if(defined('DFfdcxc58xasdGJWdfa5hDFG')): // Random unique security key

    return array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'bob',
        'pass' => '123',
        'name' => 'data'
    );

endif;
```

**Database Class:**

```
interface Dashboard{

    public function initialize($actual);

}

define('DFfdcxc58xasdGJWdfa5hDFG',0); // Random unique security key

class Configuration{

    protected $config = require_once('Config.php');
    protected $api_key = "Xc4FeSo09PxNcTTd3793XJrIiK";

}

class DashboardSettings{

    public $alerts = array();
    protected $comments = true;
    protected $read_only = false;
    protected $safe_mode = false;

}

class Database extends Configuration extends DashboardSettings implements Dashboard{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = mysqli_connect($this->config[0],$this->config[1],$this->config[2],$this->config[3]);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno){ array_push($this->alerts, 'Error connecting to Database...'); $this->safe_mode = true; }
    }

    public function initialize($actual = null){
        if($actual != null){
            // Handle incomming setting - reference DashboardSettings
        } else {
            // Handle all settings - reference DashboardSettings
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No, it is not possible

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this, even in a separate method?

Comment: Load the config and pass it as constructor arguments. (`new Configuration($con)`)

Comment: The issue is, the configuration file is being done using `file_put_contents` so I cannot think of how to achieve that with maximum security. @Yoshi

Comment: I don't see why this is anymore of a security risk than any other way of including the file *as code*. If you want to be safe (because the contents of the file are outside of your control) then you need to parse it as text and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. When you assign require_once(); to a variable, the variable turns into a boolean with 1 in case the file was included successfully, or 0 otherwise (useless in require_once() as it returns a fatal error if it fails.
So, doing:

```
<?php
$hello = require_once("./hello.php");
echo $hello; // Prints 1.
?>
```

Anyway, if you create a php file that returns something, as for example:

```
FILE: require.php
<?php
$hello = "HELLO";
return $hello;
?>
```

In this case, the previous example would be different:

```
<?php
$hello = require_once("./require.php");
echo $hello; // Prints HELLO.
?>
```

So, you cannot store the function itself to execute it later, but you can store returned values from the required or included files. Anyway, if you explain better what are you using it for, I maybe able to help you better.

Answer By @David Álvarez

Comment: Therefore, if I added `return $con;` inside the Configuration file, my `print_r` should then work? This is very much appreciated! - Haha, perfect. This worked!

Comment: @KyleE4K If you go and use `return`, please don't `return $con`, as this `$con` variable will then still be present in your requiring script. Just use `return array(...);`. And minor nitpicking, `require_*` (and similar) are statements, not functions. Drop the parenthesis ;)

Comment: I've used a `define()` for security ;) I appreciate this comment though and have done `return array(...)` and just stuck in in my constructor like you said :P @Yoshi